# Pandas - Complex lookup in code-value-pair-look-like-dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lookup

I'm fighting with pandas.

I have a dataframe with code-value-pairs (from an external source) like this:

```
c = {'attribute_name': ['heat_production', 'heat_production', 'heat_production', 'heat_emission', 'heat_emission' ],
     'attribute_code': [7410, 7420, 7430, 4211, 4220],
     'attribute_text': ['Heating with oil', 'Heating with gas', 'Central heating', 'Radiator', 'Floor']}
codes = pd.DataFrame(data=c)
```

Then there is a separate dataframe like this:

```
b = {'adress': ['Teststreet 1', ' Teststreet 2'],
     'heat_production': [7420, 7410]}
buildings = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
```

**Goal is** to add a column into the buildings-dataframe contain the texts for the heating-codes.

If possible I would like not to change the structure of the dataframe containing the codes.

A simple 'static' lookup in the code-df like this works fine:

```
codes['attribute_text'][(codes['attribute_name'] == 'heat_production') & (codes['attribute_code'] == 7410)]
```

But as soon as start to apply it dynamically to the entier dataframe like:

```
buildings.assign(heating_txt = codes['attribute_text'][(codes['attribute_name'] == 'heat_production') & (codes['attribute_code'] == buildings['heat_production'])])
```

**I get errors like:** ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
s1 = pd.Series([0, 1])
s2 = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])
s1 == s2
```

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

This error is because the indices of s1 and s2 are different.

then you can use `eq` instead of `==`

```
s1.eq(s2)
```

output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Your code below caused the error

```
codes['attribute_code'] == buildings['heat_production']
```

However, you do not need to use `eq` instead of `==` to fix errors. With your logic, fixing the error won't give you the desired output.

From now on, ask how to produce the desired output rather than asking about fixing errors. In most cases, fixing errors will not reach the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try merging? I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're aiming to do but this might help?

```
buildings.merge(codes[['attribute_code','attribute_text']],left_on = ['heat_production'], right_on = ['attribute_code'], how = 'inner')
```

This ends up with a print out of:

```
          adress  heat_production  attribute_code    attribute_text
0   Teststreet 1             7420            7420  Heating with gas
1   Teststreet 2             7410            7410  Heating with oil
```

The repeat of the key column could always be done away with with `.drop(['attribute_code'])` if it irritates you.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just change the header in the buildings df from 'heat_production' to 'attribute_code' and then just merge on that and then you won't have the repeat key column. Not sure if that's a possibility for you or if the headers are fixed